# How to toggle a fixed position class on a div on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, toggleclass

I've been trying for ages to fix this div to the top of my screen when I scroll to it, but it's not working for some reason. Upon searching many answers, I think it might be because $(window).height() returns inaccurate values on Chrome.

What I'm trying to accomplish on my website is for a block of text to stick (fix) at the middle of the window when I scroll down to it, and then unfix later on in the page when the bottom of it gets inline with an image. I will be doing this by vertically aligning the text in a transparent div that is the same height as the viewport (100vh) that will fix when it reaches the top of the screen, and unfixing it when the bottom of this div touches the top of another transparent div that starts as the image ends.

The solution must be responsive, since I'm planning for the website to go on all platforms. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I have - it just doesn't work for me:

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#words_box");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos <= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("fix");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("fix"); 
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="words_box">

    <h2 id="about_words">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
    </h2>

</div>

<img id="about_words" src="any image that takes up the right side of the viewport."/>
```

**CSS**

```
#about_words {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 52.5%;
    font-size:2.17vw;
    text-align:left !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}   

#words_box {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align:center;
    float:left; 
    margin-top:-10.4em;
    position:static;
    z-index:-10000;
}

.fix{
    position:fixed !important;
    margin-right: 5.555555%;
    top:10.4em;
}
```

Comment: Not completely following what you're wanting and sorry I don't have too much time to spend on it right now - but I do notice you're not closing document ready. The }); at the end of your javascript is closing window scroll - you need another }); after that on another line to close document ready. This likely won't fix your problem but it will certainly help!

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually do have a }); at the end but somehow missed it in the code box. I've edited it now. And what I want is for a div to fix when it reaches the top of the window, and unfix later down in the page when it reaches the end of another image, if that helps. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just curious, since you want a responsive solution, have you considered using Bootstrap? It has this functionality built in with the affix component.

Comment: I have considered Bootstrap, but have no idea on how to use it. I will most likely try and teach myself sooner or later, though, seeming as it does seem like a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what was going wrong, if you were wondering. It was an issue with Google Chrome, since the jQuery was working in Safari but not Chrome. I fixed it by replacing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

with

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
```

Now the div does fix to the top when I add the class .fix to it.

Comment: That's actually been deprecated, better to use `$(window).on('load', function() {`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware. Thanks for telling me! @Shikkediel

Comment: No biggie, it'll still work for now but might get removed at some point. If you have a few minutes to spare and would like to read a bit more on how to optimise this sort of thing you could have a look at this post too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33264826/3168107.

Comment: From what I read, the issue may depend on if the image is cached or not when going to the page. You can't get it's calculated height before it's been fully loaded. But for new visitors (that have definitely not cached anything) and just to be sure in general, this should be the best approach.