# Detecting if a user has scrolled away from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The obvious answer to this is to simply attach an event to the scroll event:

```
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
       scrolled = true;
   } else {
       scrolled = false;
   }
});
```

However, creator of jQuery, [John Resig's blogpost from 2011](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) states: **It’s a very, very, bad idea to attach handlers to the window scroll event.**

And recommends the following:

```
var didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        // Check your page position
    }
}, 250);
```

Has anything changed in the past five years? Is John Resig's solution still the best?

Comment: `Detecting if a user has scrolled` I don't understand why dont' you simply use: `$(window).one('scroll', function(){didScroll = true;});`??? (here using `one()`)  EDIT: i understand you want to check only once if user has scrolled the window, maybe i misunderstood title

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry you're right. I inserted the wrong code.

Comment: Won't your example 'recommendation' attach the event listener EVERY 250ms? Surely this is the antithesis of a good recommendation, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Moob Ya this has nothing to do with posted link recommendation

Comment: You could simply use that: `var scrolled = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    scrolled = !!this.scrollY;
});` And if for some reason you have performance issue, debounce event a little

Comment: @Moob Thanks for pointing that out. Doh!

Comment: Note that it won't work in IE though, that'll need `window.pageYOffset`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd hate to argue with the creator of jQuery but having a brilliant mind doesn't necessarily mean you're always right of course. Using a delay on scroll might ruin any animation based on the event. I've spent a ridiculous amount of time investigating the scroll event and making plugins and demos based on it and it seems somewhat of an urban myth that it triggers very often of most devices.

Here's a small demo to test the amount - the maximum seems to be the display refresh rate :

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVoBNj?editors=001)

Unless the browser has smooth scrolling enabled, mousewheeling or panning will only result in a *single* event getting triggered. And even if that's not the case, most machines are very well equipped to handle as many calls as the frame rate will allow - provided the rest of the web page is built well.

That last bit is the biggest issue, browsers can handle quite a bit of script at small intervals but what could slow down execution most is badly written markup. The biggest bottlenecks are therefore often repaints. This can be well inspected when using developer tools.

Some examples of that are having big blocks of fixed position elements and animations that aren't based on `transform` but use pixel values instead. Both trigger unnecessary repaints which have a huge impact on performance. These problems aren't directly related to how often scroll fires.

Using fixed position elements, repaints on webkit related browsers can be prevented with this hack :

```
.fixed {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

This creates a separate stacking order, making the content independent of it's surroundings and preventing the complete page from being repainted. Firefox seems to do this by default but unfortunately I haven't found a property yet that will work with IE so it's best to avoid these kinds of elements in any case, especially if their size is a large portion of the viewport.

**The following was not yet implemented at the time of writing of the article mentioned.**

And that would be `requestAnimationFrame` which now has very good browser support. With this, functions can be executed in a way that's not forced on the browser. So if there are complex functions inside the scroll handler, it would be a very good idea to use this.

Another optimisation is to use flagging and not run anything unless it needs to. A helpful tool in this can be to add classes and check for their presence. Here's the approach I generally use :

```
$(function() {

var flag, modern = window.requestAnimationFrame;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if (!$(this).scrollTop()) {

        if (flag) {
        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);
        else doSomething();
        flag = false;
        }
    }
    else if (!flag) {

        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(doMore);
        else doMore();
        flag = true;
    }
});

function doSomething() {

    // special magic
}

function doMore() {

    // other shenanigans
}
});
```

And an example of how toggling a class could be used to determine a boolean :

```
$(function() {

var modern = window.requestAnimationFrame;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var flag = $('#element').hasClass('myclass');

    if (!$(this).scrollTop()) {

        if (flag) {
        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);
        else doSomething();
        $('#element').removeClass('myclass');
        }
    }
    else if (!flag) {

        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(doMore);
        else doMore();
        $('#element').addClass('myclass');
    }
});

function doSomething() {

    // special magic
}

function doMore() {

    // other shenanigans
}
});
```

If it doesn't interfere with any desired functionality, debouncing the event can be a good approach of course. It can be as simple as :

```
$(function() {

var doit, modern = window.requestAnimationFrame;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    clearTimeout(doit);

    doit = setTimeout(function() {

        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);
        else doSomething();

    }, 50);
});

function doSomething() {

    // stuff going on
}
});
```

Below in the comments, Kaiido had a few valid points. Apart from having to raise the scope of the variable that defines the timeout, this approach may not be too useful in practice because it will only execute a function *after* scrolling has finished. I'd like to refer to [this interesting article](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/), leading to the conclusion that what would be more effective than debouncing here is *throttling* - making sure the events only run the function a maximum amount per time unit, closer to what was proposed in the question. Ben Alman made [a nice little plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) for this (note it was written in 2010 already).

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epVzLN?editors=001)

I've managed to extract only the part needed for throttling, it can still be used in a similar way :

```
$(window).scroll($.restrain(50, someFunction));
```

Where the first argument is the amount of time within which only a single event will execute the second parameter - the callback function. Here's the underlying code :

```
(function(window, undefined) {

var $ = window.jQuery;

$.restrain = function(delay, callback) {

    var executed = 0;

    function moduleWrap() {

        var elapsed = Date.now()-executed;

        function runIt() {

            executed = Date.now();
            callback.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        if (elapsed > delay) runIt();
    }

    return moduleWrap;
};
})(this);
```

What will happen inside the function to be executed can still slow down the process of course. One example of what should always be avoided is using `.css()` to set style and placing any calculations inside it. This is quite detrimental to performance.

Has to be mentioned as well that the flagging code makes more sense when toggling at a certain point *down* the page instead of at the top because that position won't fire multiple times. So the check on the flag itself there could be left out in the scope of the question.

Doing this right, it would make sense to also check the scroll position on page load and toggle on the basis of that. Opera is particularly stubborn with this - it resumes the cached position *after* page load. So a small timeout is best suited :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

        // check scroll position and set flag

    }, 20);
});
```

In general I'd say - don't avoid using the scroll event, it can provide very nice effects on a web page. Just be vigilant of how it all sticks together.

Comment: Very good answer, well detailed. Just to let you know, your debounce function won't work the way you want : if `doit` is set only in the scope of the scroll handler, you won't ever clear it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you hit the exact point I was having doubt about. Good eye for detail. If you look at the demo near the top, you'll notice I raised the scope a level there. Gonna have to keep that in mind.

Comment: also, what I don't really like in this debounce, is that it actually waits for the event flow ends, which means that the `doSomething` will only execute at the last event+timeout. I think of debounce more like ["do it now once and don't redo if timeout has not passed"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33259926/3702797). But that surely depends a lot on what is `Something`.

Comment: Correct again, nothing I can say. I'll have a good look at how useful that bit really is and maybe change it around somewhat to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here solution that I use:

```
function bindScrollObserverEvent() {
    var self = this;
    $.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {
        var $this =$(this),
            self = this;
        $this.scroll(function() {
            if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
                clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
            }
            $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback, 250, self));
        });
    };

        $(window).scrollStopped(function() {
          //You code
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

The two snippets are differents : the first one only checks if we're at top of the page, while the second one checks if we've scrolled (whatever our position) on the page the last 250ms and only then, execute our script.

I personally think that an even better solution than this "recommendation" is, like proposed in comments, to [debounce your event](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).
A small example :

```
var scrolling, timeout;

function callback(){
  // do something
  }

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(!scrolling){
    // first time in last 250 ms we did scroll
    scrolling = true;
    callback();
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){scrolling = false}, 250);
    }
  else{
    // we already scrolled less than 250ms ago, reset the timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){scrolling = false}, 250);
    }
});
```

This way, if you stay like an hour at the same position, you won't have called a single time your function, while in the proposed snippet, you would have called it 3600000 times.

What you do here however, is just to set a 250ms timeout and reset it on every scroll event. That may happen fast, but, even if I don't have any paper about it, I'm pretty confident that this won't block any modern device or js interpreter.

For the first snippet, well... really it just serves to detect whether we're at top or not and even if I doubt of its usefulness, I can't see how to really improve it... except by changing `scrolled` to `notAtTop`. But as pointed by @AlexBerd, it shouldn't even be set to false at start, since we don't know the scroll position on load so maybe it should be `var notAtTop = $(window).scrollTop() > 0;`